# Event is not defined” in firefox.

Tags: javascript, jquery

I notice some post,
tried   evt.pageX    window.event.pageX
 but I is not work.

```
var curr_elem = [[0,0],[0,0]];

$("*").click(function(){ 

            curr_elem[0][0]=event.pageX-pageXOffset;
            curr_elem[0][1]=event.pageY-pageYOffset;
            $("#lable5").text("X "+curr_elem[0][0]);
            $("#lable6").text("Y "+curr_elem[0][1]);

    });
```

Or maybe exist better way to get mouse X Y inside "click" event. Its working on Chrome and IE. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `$("*").click(function(event){ `

Answer (score 2):

pass `event` in a function

```
$("*").click(function(event){
```

NOTE: some of the browser does not get event ,so you have to pass `e`,

Answer (score 0):

`event` is not defined. you're not passing a parameter to the callback within the `click` handler.